# Актуальное время выполнения программы

Tags: python, время, datetime

Я измеряю время выполнения программы при помощи модулей `datetime` и `timeit`, код выглядит следующим образом:

```
def func():
    time_start = timeit.default_timer()

    # some code here

    return timedelta(round(timeit.default_timer() - time_start, 0))
```

После выполнения мне возвращается время выполнения в виде, например:

> 0:00:08

Я хочу сделать так,чтобы возвращалось только использованное время. То есть, чтобы в примере вернулось `08`

Comment: У `timedelta` есть аттрибут `seconds` для того, чтобы забрать только секунды. Но, не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать. Что, если время выполнения программы будет 1:00:42? Какой вывод вы ожидаете?

Comment: @mkkik В Вашем случае я бы хотел получить полное время выполнения,просто в моем примере есть время **0:00**:08,нули которых,я бы не хотел отображать

Comment: Да, и вы в `timedelta` передаете секунды как дни.